# problem with Line integral of vector field

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus, line-integrals

Taking the xyz-coordinate system with $i,j,k$ are the unit vector of each axis, there is a Vector Field $F = {5x+y, 3y-2xz, z} = (5x+y)i + (3y-2xz)j + zk$ I want to find the integral of F on the line connect 2 point $A(1,2,0)$ and $B=(3,-4,1)$

$$\int \vec{F}d\vec{h}$$

for

$$dh= idx + jdy + zdk$$

Then

$$\int \vec{F}d\vec{h} = \int((5x+y)i + (3y-2xz)j + zk)(idx + jdy + zdk) = \int (5x+y)dx + (3y-2xy)dy + zdz$$

I got stuck at this point because this doesn't look like multi-variable integral since there is no product $dxdydz$ like I have learned from my math book

Comment: $dx\,dy\,dz$ would show up in integrations over a volume. Here you go along a line.

Comment: Yes, from all thing I read from my book, it's always like that and there's no case showing me how to deal with (dx+dy+dz) and again, I still don't know is this triple integral or not since it take 3 variable into account

Comment: Those three variables are not independent. You can express two of them in terms of the third, or all of them in terms of one other variable, like idm showed expressing $x, y, z$ in terms of $t$. In the end it must boil down to a single integration.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to parametrize $[A,B]$. Thus
$$[A,B]=\{\gamma(t)=(1+2t, 2-6t,t)\mid t\in[0,1]\}$$
and thus $\dot\gamma(t)=\frac{d\vec \gamma(t)}{dt}=(2,-6,1)$
Therefore

$$\int_{[A,B]}\vec F \cdot d\vec h=\int_0^1 F(\gamma(t))\cdot \dot\gamma(t)dt=\int_0^1 F(1+2t, 2-6t,t)\cdot \frac{d\gamma(t)}{dt}dt=\int_0^1\begin{pmatrix}5(1+2t)+(2-5t)\\3(2-6t)-2t(1+2t)\\t\end{pmatrix}\cdot \begin{pmatrix}2\\-6\\ 1\end{pmatrix}dt=...$$

Comment: Hi, can you tell me what is the meaning of the dot sign you use above the parametric line equation $\gamma$

Comment: $\dot\gamma(t)=\frac{d\gamma (t)}{dt}$

Comment: Thank, but isn't line integral will equal $\int\vec{F(\gamma(t))}|\dot\gamma(t)|dt$ so why your solution is  $\int\vec{F(\gamma(t))}d\gamma(t)$

Comment: it would be this if $F:\mathbb R^3\to \mathbb R$. But here $F:\mathbb R^3\to\mathbb R^3$, therefore is the formula I gave above.

Answer (score 1):

Continuing idm's calculation
\begin{align}
I 
&= 
\int\limits_0^1
\left(
\begin{matrix}
5(1+2t)+(2-6t) \\
3(2-6t)-2(1+2t)t \\
t
\end{matrix}
\right)
\cdot
\left(
\begin{matrix}
2 \\
-6 \\
1
\end{matrix}
\right)
\,
dt \\
&=
\int\limits_0^1 24 t^2+129 t-22 \, dt \\
&=
\left[8 t^3 + \frac{129}{2} t^2 - 22 t \right]_0^1 \\
&=
8 + \frac{129}{2} - 22 \\
&= 
\frac{101}{2}
\end{align}